# Keep data after Heroku dyno restart

Tags: heroku, twitter, bots

I have a twitter bot hosted at Heroku, and once a day the server reboots. I have a text file that is constantly being modified, and when the server is restarted the changes in that file are lost. Does anyone know how to keep that file updated when the server is restarted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,you have to pay heroku for dynos : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos
Or you can always choose to deploy it somewhere else

Comment: Do you know of any other free places to deploy?

Comment: I only know about https://firebase.google.com/ , you could try to watch some tutorials about how to deploy on firebase(they also provided a database if u need,firestore, everythings free).good luck

Answer (score 1):

Heroku file system is ephemeral and gets wiped out at every restart.
A solution (if you want to keep using Heroku) is to use an external service to persist your data:

1. Amazon  S3, see [Heroku article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)
2. Github, an easy and **free** option if you need to perform simple get/put, see an [example](https://github.com/gcatanese/HerokuFiles)
3. A database ([Atlas MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) has a free tier which can be used in cases like yours)